# How do I create an index with hyperlinks to the page numbers in MS Word 2010?

Tags: text, ms-word, hyperlink, edit

When clicked on the page number in Index Table it should take me to the respective page & when clicked on the page number of any page I should return to Index page.

I have created the first page as a tabular Index with page numbers in second column and added page numbers in footer for all the pages including Index page. But I am unable to hyperlink the pages. I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/157951-post4.html